# How do you best structure your DynamoDb for multiple query parameters

Tags: scalability, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index, amazon-dynamodb

In context of a tracker system, I have a situation, where the user's device deliver location data to backend and the system subsequently queries that data both per user and in bulk.
The structure of the data is as follows:

```
{"user_id": "user_1", "timestamp": "2020-10-31 07:05:10.153777+00:00", "location": "XYZ", "details": "PQR"}
```

The queries that we need are:

```
Get all location and details data for X<timestamp<Y
```

and

```
Get all location and details data for user_id=P and X<timestamp<Y
```

The total size of database would be around 10 TB
I am a DynamoDb newbie, and am not sure I understand the concept of partitionKey very well. Currently I would plan to use a table with partitionKey as user_id and rangekey as timestamp, and then create a secondary global index with "day" out of timestamp for satisfying the first query.

- Does anybody have advice about how should the DynamoDb be structured
  for best scaling and performance?
- Does anybody have any
  advice/criticism about the currently suggested structure?

Answer (score 0):

> I would plan to use a table with partitionKey as user_id and rangekey as timestamp

I think that's a good structure for satisfying your second query. You could specify a user, then filter by the desired date/time range.

For your first query, trying to request X<timestamp<Y might give you trouble. Take a look at this page on [constructing a Key Condition Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions):

> You must specify the partition key name and value as an equality condition.

In other words, even if you build a GSI on the "day" portion of the timestamp, I'm not aware of a way to do a X<timestamp<Y query directly - the name of a single partition must be given.

Based on what you've said, you could still use a GSI indexed on the "day" portion of your timestamp and query it sequentially, a day at a time.

This is sort of the idea behind [write sharding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-gsi-sharding.html), where you explicitly are controlling the number of partitions in your GSI to allow for direct querying. In your case, creating a GSI indexed on the "day" would give you one partition per day that can be queried directly using an = operator, as is required by dynamodb.